# WordPress Contact Form 7 Redirect via Functions.php

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I have the following code as a function to add the form data to the database usermeta table then send an email which all works. The issue is the form stays stuck on the loading image and I can't find anyway to get it to redirect or display a confirmation message, any help would be much appreciated. I've tried using another function with wpcf7_mail_sent but nothing happens, tried additional settings for the form and am stuck.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7import',1);
function cf7import() {
$title = $contact_form->title;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $submission ) 
{
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
$formtitle = $cfdata->title; } 
if ( $formtitle == 'Apply Form') { 
}
 global $wpdb; 
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 update_user_meta( $user_id, 'prefix', $posted_data['prefix'] );
 update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $posted_data['first-name'] );
 update_user_meta( $user_id, 'middle_name', $posted_data['middle-name'] );

global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 $email_address = 'contact@website.com';
 // write the email content
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$header .= "From:" . $email_address;
$subject = 'New Application Form';
$message = "Hi,<br/><br/>".$posted_data['first-name'].' '.$posted_data['last-name']."<br/><br/>";
$message .= "Your application has been submitted successfully";
wp_mail($current_user->user_email, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that $contact_form isn't defined.

You can use something like this:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7import', 1);

function cf7import($contact_form) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ){
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data(); 
        $formtitle   = $contact_form->title(); 
    } 

    if ( $formtitle == 'Apply Form') { 

        global $wpdb, $current_user; 

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'prefix', $posted_data['prefix'] );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $posted_data['first-name'] );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'middle_name', $posted_data['middle-name'] );

        get_currentuserinfo();

        $email_address = 'contact@website.com';

        // write the email content
        $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $header .= "From:" . $email_address;

        $subject = 'New Application Form';

        $message = "Hi,<br/><br/>".$posted_data['first-name'].' '.$posted_data['last-name']."<br/><br/>";
        $message .= "Your application has been submitted successfully";
        wp_mail($current_user->user_email, $subject, $message, $header);

    }

}
```

Also made the code more readable and fixed some other issues (empty if conditional and undefined $header).

Comment: thanks for your help but it still just stays stuck with the loading gif with no on page confirmation the form has been sent

Answer (score 0):

The code actually works as it should it was a conflict with the "WP Job Manager - Contact Listing" plugin that was stopping it from working